# Is it appropriate to post a question to illustrate the Chronicles of Darkness combat system?

Tags: discussion, questions, self-answering

As some people have noted, there are not a lot of published examples of round-by-round combat worked out in the CoD system for many splats.  I would like to post a question along the lines of "what is a good example of how combat works in Demon: The Descent" and then work out an example (no doubt with many helpful corrections from the SE).  Similar questions might be posted for other CoD splats or even other gaming systems.

However, this isn't (AFAIK) a standard sort of question on RPG.se.  Is it kosher?

Answer (score 11):

## Yes, sorta.

I agree with V2 that the way you pose it in your post here--"what's a good example of combat"--would be broad and unclear.

However, it sounds like you've experienced difficulty sorting out combat in D:tD. Or you've helped others sort out that sort of difficulty. So leverage that experience: think of a scenario or combination of elements that gave someone trouble and then pose *that* question: "How, step by step, will combat play out when Alice brings her sonic pliers to a quantum spanner fight between Bob and Charlie?"

Then in the question-post (a) clearly state that this is a real(ish) scenario you/someone had trouble with, (b) what about it gives/gave trouble, (c) this is the way you explain things to players to not only answer the specific question but also to illustrate the underlying principles, and (d) drop a link to this meta.

That sort of approach has worked for me--[this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/92490/23970) is a similar sort of example--and I wish you luck with it.

Comment: I'd like to do this for just a few rounds of normal combat showing initiative, the role of defense and armor, how Ephemerals work in combat, etc. without even resorting to weird demon powers.  So I don't have a question about a specific power, but I have a desire to see the combat mechanics illustrated.

Comment: @KieranMullen: That sounds like it'd be a number of separate questions (and self-answers), not a single question.

Comment: @KieranMullen I don't know enough about the system (Storyteller virgin, here) to have a good sense of how large/small a "chunk" of combat would make sense to carve off for a Q/A. Do remember, though, the word limit is something like 30K: long answers aren't inherently bad, though I suspect that a 20K-word answer will occasion plenty of scrutiny. My impulse (esp. with non-D&D questions) is to say "let it rip" and see how mainsite reacts. From this perspective it's clearly topical and stems from actual problems--check and check!

Comment: @nitsua60 (Correction: it's 30k characters rather than words. ([An example of 10k chars, for scale.](https://techcrunch.com/2016/01/05/140-to-10k/)) Still a lot, but yes, potentially relevant to keep in mind as a limit.)

Comment: Aah--thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

In the words of Mick Jones of Big Audio Dynamite, "[Break it on down — bless you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rPrPNpzLHIk)." It's so much easier to address these kinds of things when you've got discrete questions at the decision points than in one long work. Your answerers will thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## It'd likely be too broad, as currently worded

I'm not familiar with the CoD combat system in particular. However, a question asking generically "How does combat work?" seems too broad, as there can be many different aspects to combat. (Compare this to, say, a question about how a particular spell, magic item, or class feature works in one system.)

I think it could be asked in a form that's suitable to the RPG.SE format if you phrase it more specifically, rather than asking about all combat as a whole.

Comment: It's a fault of the publisher, I suppose, but there are not a lot of play-by-play examples.  Again, SE might not be the proper venue for addressing this need.  That's why I raised the question here first. However, a forum like reddit seems even worse since what's needed is a nice, well-edited, archival answer that illustrates each aspect of the combat mechanics. Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: @KieranMullen: As mentioned in my reply to your comment on nitsua60's answer, this might work as several different questions, one about each specific aspect you're confused about. In such a broad sense, though, a single overall question about every aspect of combat wouldn't really be suited to the RPG.SE format. nitsua60's answer gives a good example of how to scope it more narrowly.